# Nhibernate 3.3.1 OpenEdge dialect generates bad like statement from Linq

Tags: sql, linq, nhibernate, openedge, dialect

I am creating a new NHibernate dialect to work with an OpenEdge 10.2a database over ODBC. I have been using the dialect in NHibernate 2.1 with no problems, but when porting it to NHibernate 3.3.1 I'm having problems with the generated querys Like statement.

When using the dialect on NHibernate 3.3.1, like statements are generated like below for a linq query using startswith("sometest").

```
select test from tests
where testname like (?||'%');
p0 = 'sometest' [Type: String (8)]
```

This has changed since NHibernate 2.1, and the OpenEdge database does not support this. The same query in NHibernate 2.1 looks like:

```
select test from tests
where testname like ?;
p0 = 'sometest%'
```

I have tried using the MsSql2005Dialect, and this changes the generated SQL a little to:

```
select test from tests
where testname like (?+'%');
p0 = 'sometest' [Type: String (8)]
```

Notice the pipes that became a plus.

What causes these changes, and how can I affect it so I can can make my dialect work on NH 3.3.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this will not work out of the box for databases that do not support concat expressions as LIKE parameters. See [NH-2254](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2254)

The workaround is to extend the LINQ provider. [Here's a sample](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com.ar/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html).

Comment: Why the difference in the operators (|| vs +) to concat - what are they based on, since they change based on dialect?

Comment: Those represent the not-quite-standard `concat` function. The base `Dialect` class uses `||`, which is the standard for many databases, while SQL Server and Sybase use `+`, MySql uses an actual `concat()` function, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Changed the dialect to use a concat funcion.

Answer (score 0):

I Have a Workaround for this problem!
As you know, you can create your owns **Dialects Classes** for the Nhibernate.

I´ve been using the Dialect from this project: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2327

But i´ve changed the concat function
I´ve added this line to the class:

```
RegisterFunction("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(NHibernateUtil.String, concat(", ",+", ")"));
```

it does generates this Like statement: like concat('%'+?+'%','')

**Explanation:** The concat function of OpenEdge accepts just 2 variables, but, magically inside the concat function, it does accept a + signal to concat string.

**Updating**: You can also take the [OpenEdgeDialect](https://github.com/zmp/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/OpenEdgeDialect.cs)  class that I made.